# java fibonacci of ANY first two numbers

Tags: java, recursion, fibonacci, tail-recursion

I need to write java methods to compute the Fibonacci series of ANY first two numbers imputed by the user, let's say that the user inputs `10` and `20`, and wants the first 5 numbers of the series, the output would be `10 20 30 50 80`. I have already implemented an iterative method that does this, but my trouble is with the RECURSIVE method to accomplish it.

```
public int fRec(int n)
    {
        //base case of recursion
        if ((n == 0) || (n == 1))
            return n;
        else
            //recursive step
            return fRec(n-1) + fRec(n-2);
    }
```

This is the typical recursive method to the fibonacci series, the `n` parameter represents up to what number the user wants the series to run, but how can i modify it to to make sure that the series uses the first two numbers that the user wants the series to begin with?

Comment: Note: if you use recursion without memorisation your method will take `O(e^n)` which is quickly longer than the age of the universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with specific numbers in the series they will need to be returned for 0 and 1:

```
public int fib(int n, int start1, int start2) {
    switch (n) {
        case 0: return start1;
        case 1: return start2;
        default: return fib(n-1, start1, start2) + fib(n-2, start1, start2);
    }
}
```

This is a pretty laborious way to calculate several members of the series as it's going all the way back to the start each time. Better would be to encapsulate in a class:

```
class Fib {
    private int previous;
    private int current;

    public Fib(int start1, int start2) {
        this.previous = start1;
        this.current = start2;
    }

    public int next() {
        int temp = previous + current;
        previous = current;
        current = successor;
        return current;
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh i see, i knew it was something silly but just couldn't see it. thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

I would use [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) with a `Map<Integer,Long>` and pass the `first` and `second` terms to the **constructor**. For example,

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public Fibonacci(long first, long second) {
        memo.put(0, first);
        memo.put(1, second);
    }
    Map<Integer, Long> memo = new HashMap<>();

    public long fRec(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
            return memo.get(n);
        }
        long r = fRec(n - 2) + fRec(n - 1);
        memo.put(n, r);
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fibonacci f = new Fibonacci(10, 20);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(f.fRec(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
10
20
30
50
80
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of calculating Fibonacci series of any first two numbers.

public class StackOverflow {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int first = 10, second = 20;
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
    recursive(first, second, 2);
}

public static void recursive(int first, int second, int count) {
        if (count != 5){
            int temp = first+second;
            first= second;
            second = temp;
            System.out.println(second);
            recursive(first, second, ++count);
        }       
}
```

}